Is this the best way to implement a concurrent integer in C#
 internal class Employee
 {
     internal int concurrentState; 

     internal void SetConcurrentState(int concurrentStatus) 
     { 
         Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.concurrentState, concurrentStatus);
     }
     internal int GetConcurrentState() 
     { 
         return Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this.concurrentState, 
                                            0, 
                                            -this.concurrentState); 
     }
}

Like the title says, is this the best way to implement a concurrent (atomic) integer in C#? I only need to get a value so the convoluted get method defeats the comparison operation. It seems that Microsoft would have provided a better way.
Addendum: @mjwills posted a link to the C Sharp spec and from it is this...

9.6 Atomicity of variable references Reads and writes of the following data types shall be atomic: bool, char, byte, sbyte, short, ushort,
uint, int, float, and reference types. In addition, reads and writes
of enum types with an underlying type in the previous list shall also
be atomic. Reads and writes of other types, including long, ulong,
double, and decimal, as well as user-defined types, need not be
atomic. Aside from the library functions designed for that purpose,
there is no guarantee of atomic read-modify-write, such as in the case
of increment or decrement.

However a CLI document says atomic ops are are garanteed only on the condition of proper word boundary alignment in linked this text...

A conforming CLI shall guarantee that read and write access of
built-in primitive value types and pointers to properly aligned memory
locations no larger than the native word size (the size of type native
int) is atomic (see §I.12.6.2) when all the write accesses to a
location are the same size.

Second Addendum: This answer to a similar question points out that later changing an int to a long might break atomicity of a read.  So a good reason to use Interlocked.CompareExchange is to avoid relying on the inherent atomicity of a reaon on an int that might get revised to a long. This is now a closed question but if I were to answer it, I would answer that this is a good method and the risk of breakage was probably what I was thinking about when I wrote it (way back when).   I would clean it up by using the equivalent Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref v, 0, 0).

That GetConcurrentState isn't great, what happens if the value was int.MinValue? Why not just use Interlocked.Read? Or use the more correct Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this.concurrentState, 0, 0). It also depends what processor, and whether threads are both reading and writing, or only one or the other.

This link says whether an int read/write is atomic depends on the processor so given most are 32 or 64 bit, int would be atomic. The spec is explicit that int is atomic. https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/standard-v6/standard/variables.md#96-atomicity-of-variable-references If you can point us to anything that says otherwise we can discuss (well the discussion will be "that link is wrong", but regardless.

No it won't. If it's non-zero it will stay the same value, it won't be replaced. Think about the logic again.

@mjwills Stock purchase order number of shares bought.

So if the child writes the value 3, then the value 4, then the value 5 but the parent fails to read the 3 and 4 in time (i.e. only sees the 5), what should happen? Have you considered instead something like a queue or pub-sub or blocking collection etc to co-ordinate communication between the two of them? This is a classic XY problem - you are failing to tell us the important bit that will help us get you on the right track.

@mjwills  I'm not worried about that.  An int is 4 bytes (more than 1 byte) so I need the read and write to be atomic.  This might fail on a 16 bit processor but since you said the spec says it's not processor dependent, that's great.

It will not fail. The spec explicitly says it is atomic. On what basis do you not trust the spec? And if you don't trust the spec, why trust C# at all?

@mjwills  It's not that I don't trust the spec. It's that I never saw where the spec said ops on primitive objects are atomic and not dependent on data bus width.

You saw the spec before you stated This might fail. What makes you think This might fail?

@mjwills It won't fail because you said the spec said it won't.  I was just assuming it would fail on a 16 bit processor since an int is 32 bits.

There are no .NET CLI implementations for 16-bit processors that I'm aware of. I'd be interested to hear of one.

If there was one, it would be obligated to fulfil the spec.

Regardless, I think using an int as a communication method between two components is not optimal. Use a more appropriate data structure (e.g. a queue). Since if you use an int then how can the consumer differentiate between "no stocks were purchased" vs "some stocks were purchased, but it just hasn't been populated as yet"?

@mjwills I don't see how a queue solves the problem and I suspect a queue still faces the same problem. You order something online that is supposed to be delivered in 24 hours, you wait 1 year and it's still not delivered so you order again and after you place the order you get a knock on the door so you end up owning 2 of the item.

A queue at least lets you know that the consumer actually saw / consumed it. You order something online that is supposed to be delivered in 24 hours, you wait 1 year Clearly if you are talking about timeframes of a year then anything in memory is not appropriate. You'll need some kind of backing store (e.g. disk spaced queue or database). In which case the atomicity of int is a moot point.

Again, this is a XY Problem - if your business problem is "how do I ensure things get delivered to the customer" and you are focusing on "are ints atomic", can I humbly suggest you are working at the wrong level of abstraction?

@mjwills Merely an analogy. Everything I'm doing today happens in the 6.5 hours when the stock market is open.

Since if you use an int then how can the consumer differentiate between "no stocks were purchased" vs "some stocks were purchased, but it just hasn't been populated as yet"? How do you plan to solve that problem? How can you distinguish between (0 unpopulated and 0 no stocks were purchased)?

Merely an analogy. You can't use an analogy that makes queues hard, and then when I point out that it also makes your proposed solution just as hard then retreat to "well it was just an analogy". That isn't how logic and reason and discussions work. But again - this is the problem with a XY Problem. You have only given us 5% of the context. Create a new question with your actual real problem and all of the necessary context.

@mjwills I think the server that receives the orders has a rule for recognizing duplicate orders based on elapsed time.  In practice it hasn't been a problem although if I end up with double the expected quantity, I can sell half.

@H2ONaCl are you serious? "In practice it hasn't been a problem although if I end up with double the expected quantity, I can sell half" - for what exact stock market is this again?

@Fildor Interactive Brokers SMART orders. If I recall correctly, if I order 200 and after a timeout none were filled, I have cancelled and resubmitted with a different price. If it gets filled I own 200. I have never ended up owning 400. If the first order is responsible for the fill, it means that they ignored the cancel and resubmit. If the cancel was processed (not ignored), it means the second order was responsible for the fill. The doumentation doesn't disclose why this happens. I'm on a different project now but eventually I will go back and remind myself why I never got a double fill.

Sounds kind of fishy to me. Maybe I just lack context. But if it works ...

@Charlieface Interlocked.Read is 8 byte is the reason I'm not using it.

Without knowing what the Employee class is supposed to do, and how it is supposed to be used, we can say nothing about how to implement it.
